# Getting serialized json objects from django templates?

Tags: python, django, json

I need a clarification. If I for example do a view with a serialized object:

```
def sample(request):
    res = [{'name':'man'}]
    encoded = json.dumps(res)
    return render_to_response('sample/example.html',{'encoded':encoded} )
```

In my templates I pass:

```
{{encoded}}
```

Now from a python script can I do:

```
data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url/to/site).read()
```

It says ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded. But isn't {{encoded}} a json object? And if so how would I get it?

Thank you

Comment: I'd do a `print urllib2.urlopen(url/to/site).read()` first. I'm betting that Django escapes the string.

Comment: That's an *escaped* HTML string. `&quot;` should be a `'`. See my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this in your template:

```
{% autoescape off %} 
  {{ encoded }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: I get [{"name": "man"}] using autoescape in print urllib2.urlopen but still can't decode the json object. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there anything else besides that text in the page? Any HTML code?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find that there are quote marks getting escaped by Django. I had a similar problem with a Jinja2 template recently. In my case, the JSON was going into an HTML data attribute and was escaping things improperly. After I used a filter to mark it safe, it stopped escaping the quote marks and there were mismatched quotes. The solution was

```
{% set dbl_quote='"' %}
{{ encoded |replace(dbl_quote, '&quot;') |safe}}
```

but that will probably look different in Django.

You may need to use `{% autoescape off %}` or something similar instead if you're templating it straight into Javascript, etc.

Comment: And whatever you do, you might want to do something like [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/201/) to convert to JSON in a filter so if you have to mark it safe or whatever you can do that in one place inside the filter.