# Pass Python Requests (in Django views.py) Json Data to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, python-requests

I have this python code, which fetches json and parses it:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json, requests

def find(request):
    context = {}
    platformUrl = 'https://www.igdb.com/api/v1/platforms'
    platformReq = requests.get(platformUrl, headers={'Authorization': 'Token token="1234"'})
    platformData = json.loads(platformReq.text)
    platformList = platformData['platforms']
    print platformList
```

It outputs this with the print statement:

> [{u'slug': u'saturn', u'id': 32, u'name': u'Sega Saturn'}, {u'slug': u'mac', u'id': 14, u'name': u'Mac'}, {u'slug': u'vc', u'id': 47, u'name': u'Virtual Console (Nintendo)'}

I would like to pass that data to javascript and have the ID and name from the json put in this javascript. (selectize.js) This would probably require some type of for loop, could be javascript, or even djangos?:

```
    options: [
    {id: 1, title: 'Spectrometer'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Star Chart'},
    {id: 3, title: 'Electrical Tape'}
]
```

Thanks

**EDIT:** 
Following @satoru's link, I looked into it, and updated my code to this:

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
import json, requests

def find(request):
    context = {}
    platformUrl = 'https://www.igdb.com/api/v1/platforms'
    platformReq = requests.get(platformUrl, headers={'Authorization': 'Token token="1234"'})
    platformList = json.dumps(platformData)

    print platformList
    return render_to_response('find.html',{'platformList':platformList})
```

It now outputs this:

> {"platforms": [{"slug": "saturn", "id": 32, "name": "Sega Saturn"}, {"slug": "mac", "id": 14, "name": "Mac"}, {"slug": "vc", "id": 47, "name": "Virtual Console (Nintendo)"}

How would I then pass that into javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting serialized json objects from django templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214677/getting-serialized-json-objects-from-django-templates)

Comment: @satoru I don't see how that question applies to mine.

Comment: You can create a new dict containing only the keys you want, and then encode it in JSON.

Comment: @satoru I already have it in a JSON format, do I not? I got the data using python requests, and would like to pass that data I have already obtained in JSON to the javascript file. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @satoru I looked at your link even further, can you take a look at my edit and let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [template library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonify/0.2.1) to convert your platform list to a JSON object from within the template

Example(Inside your template):

```
    <script src="your_standalone_js.js">
    <script>
        var js_variable = {{platformList | jsonify }};
        function_in_standalone_js(js_variable);
    </script>
```

your_standalone_js.js:

```
    var function_in_standalone_js = function(js_variable){
        var options = js_variable['platforms'];
        //What ever you need to do with options
    };
```

Comment: It's already in the JSON format (see: platformList and what the output is), I want to pass the JSON that I'm parsing from an API into the javascript code that I provided above.

Comment: When it is passed to the template, and you try to set a Javascript variable equal to it it converts it to a string. The Jsonify library allows you to set the Javascript variable in the template like so: `var js_variable = {{platformList | jsonify }};`

Comment: I thought using `json.dumps(platformData)` converts it into JSON. Right now my output into console is: `{"platforms": [{"slug": "saturn", "id": 32, "name": "Sega Saturn"}, {"slug": "mac", "id": 14, "name": "Mac"}, {"slug": "vc", "id": 47, "name": "Virtual Console (Nintendo)"}` 
Is that not JSON?

Comment: It is JSON, but when you set it to a Javascript variable, it is converted back to a string. jsonify fixes this.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. If I was going to be putting this in a standalone JS file, how would I do that? Also, once it was in the javascript, how could I make it so that the JSON fills this javascript with it's values? 

Ex: Platform List JSON

`{"platforms": [{"slug": "saturn", "id": 32, "name": "Sega Saturn"}, {"slug": "mac", "id": 14, "name": "Mac"}, {"slug": "vc", "id": 47, "name": "Virtual Console (Nintendo)"}` 

Goes into this JS:

`options: [
    {id: 32, title: 'Sega Saturn'},
    {id: 14, title: 'Mac'},
    {id: 47, title: 'Virtual Console (Nintendo'}
]`

Comment: @AllTheGoodNamesWereTaken In the answer above @satoru shows you how to do it with my_module.js being your stand alone js file. Inside your template, set the variable the way I showed you and pass it to a function you define in your stand alone js file. To get the options variable all you have to do inside the defined function is: `var options = passed_variable["platforms"];` and you will have what you're looking for.

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer with the template code, and javascript code? I'm not understand what he means by `MyModule.initialize`. I don't know where my module comes from. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way I can test to make sure that the data is making it to my standalone js file?

Comment: `console.log(options);` and check you browser console

Comment: I have this code:   

Template:
`var platformList = {{ platformList | jsonify }};
  platformDisplay(platformList);`

Standalone JS: 
`var $(function platformDisplay() = platformDisplay(platformList) {`

It's not functioning. Thanks

Comment: Forgot the console error: `ReferenceError: platformDisplay is not defined`

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, but before we continue, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491727/include-css-and-javascript-in-my-django-template and make sure it's being included properly; and also make sure to write it as I did above.

Comment: I already have django-compressor, could I use this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576675/passing-static-url-to-file-javascript-with-django

Comment: Your answer works for everything but passing to the separate JS file, I will ask that as a different question.

Answer (score 1):

If the API already return a JSON-encoded response, you can just use `platformReq.text`. After passing it to `render_to_response`, you have access to a JSON-encoded string in your template.

Now you can design your Javascript module to be configurable with an object, for example:

```
<script src="my_module.js"></script>
<script>
   MyModule.initialize({{ json_encoded }})
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not fully understanding, where does the "my_module.js" come from?